# IBM watson natural langage classification

Tags: nlp, classification

I know you can create categories for words using IBM Watson NLP classification. But would it be possible to train or create categories based on quantities of a word. For example, one pack of cigarette is bad category, 2 packs is harmful category, 3 packs is lethal category. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am actually referring to Watson NLP-classification API

Comment: I have the answer to my own question. Watson Natural Language Classifier service will not work for differentiating classes based on quantities. The main reason behind this is because NLC aims to classify text into 'themes'. These themes should be extensible and not contextually tied to the subject of the sentence itself.

Comment: you should create an answer, and marked it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested, you can still use the NLC to classify text that does not contain numbers associated.

For example:

Text: "I never smoke"
Class: healthy

Text: "I smoke sometimes"
Class: not_so_healthy

Text: "I smoke a lot of cigarettes everyday"
Class: harmful

Text: "I never stop smoking"
Class: lethal

Answer (score 0):

Watson NLU doesn't provide slot or word categories as do the NLU solutions e.g. from Nuance/Vocon or Inferret. That means that you can classify complete utterances as the older answer below illustrates as a class/intent, but you cannot group words of similar paradigmatical meaning into word classes - e.g. class "vehicle" = car, truck, bicycle.